# Purge [e-commerce] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic, burninate-request

[e-commerce](/questions/tagged/e-commerce) tag on StackOverflow is the magnet for off-topic, opinion based and almost-no-effort questions. I think we need to do something with it.

1. Determine, if the tag belongs there. In my opinion it should be burned with unicorn fire, but I'm open to opinions, what added value could that tag have.
2. Revise the questions. I've seen some which can have this tag simply removed, but most of them are off-topic or opinion based.

Anyway, it's quite a good source of stuff to fill close queue with.

Comment: As always, if a question itself should be removed, just vote to close it without removing the tag.  I filtered on `e-commerce` this morning in the review queue and closed a lot already. I'll be revisiting that filter often until the tag is cleaned up.